# Django Static file not loading ImageField URL

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

This is for an assignment, we need to store the images in the static directory and display them on a template.  The images are stored through the item model ImageField and uploaded to the static/images directory.

Here is the template code:

```
{% load static %}
<p><a href='..'>Home</a></p>
{% block content %}
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Manufacturer</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>Image</th>
  </tr>
  {% for i in name %}
    {% if i.name == params %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{i.name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.manufacturer}}</td>
        <td>{{i.cost}}</td>
        <td>{{i.weight}}</td>
        <td><img src="{% static i.image.url %}" alt="{{i.image.url}}"></img></td>
      </tr>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</table> 
{% endblock %}
```

I have the following model code:

```
from django.db import models

class item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/')
```

Here are the current settings

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'Nice try'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = '*'
```

Currently, everything is displaying properly from the model class, however the images will not load after trying a million different tags for the img src.  We are supposed to use static so please do not suggest using media directory for the images.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: please show your views.py

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in your views.py you have:

```
name = item.objects.all()
```

and then that the variable `name` is passed to your template,

try to substitute this

```
<td><img src="{% static i.image.url %}" alt="{{i.image.url}}"></img></td>
```

With this

```
<td><img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="{{i.image.url}}"></img></td>
```

However, I would suggest you to call the `name` variable by something more representative, like `objects_list`, then you will have

```
{% for i in objects_list %}
  {% if i.name == params %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{i.name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.manufacturer}}</td>
        <td>{{i.cost}}</td>
        <td>{{i.weight}}</td>
        <td><img src="{% static i.image.url %}" alt="{{i.image.url}}"></img></td>
      </tr>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

this is way more clear.